# VS2010 Lack of shortcut, no start possible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 8 beside my VS2012 Installation, because of QT and some other stuff.

The installation worked fine, but I have no shortcut in the menu to start the IDE, not even on the Metro Surface and I also didn´t find anyone inside the installation folders.

I just repaired the complete installation, but it had no effect.

[image]

[image]

Is there a trick? Please help me :(

Comment: Have you looked in the list of programs without folders at the top of "all programs"? Sometimes my shortcut has appeared their instead.

Comment: There is nothing. I find all these shortcuts in Metro, but not the real program. I can´t believe it

Comment: okay I started the repair install of just the vs2010 package again. Not finished yet, but the menu entry popped up :) thank you anyway

Comment: I've got the same issue! Did you use the web installer? Just trying repairing it using the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

That's just because the name is incredibly dumb for the shortcut.  The executable is WDExpress.exe and the shortcut is likely "VS Express for Desktop" if you have the express edition.  So looking for visual studio doesn't find it.  Under 8.1 it's sorted under Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express in Apps sorted by category.